# Jquery / javascript nested requests and append not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, append, getjson

Hi all first off let me say sorry for any spelling mistakes or anything below i suffer from dyslexia and other learning dificulties i do try catch as many as i can but not all ways 100% i am simply trying to learn something new during this lockdown.

This is my very fist time working with jquery and i am having some issues and still trying to wrap my head around a lot of stuff i have searched on here and seen a few posts so i am sorry if this has been asked before i just trying to find someone that can help me understand

basicly i have a local api that makes requests and converts a remote xml api responce into json and i am trying to use jquery and javascript to catch and display the json into html eliments i can append to my page

first off i tried using nexted requests but this was not working the first request worked fine but did not wait for the later requests to finish before adding content to the page this resulted in partial content

i then tried to run a function inside of the first request but again this has resulted in partial output and i can only guess its because the second function is not being waited for

This is what i currently have below i have searched and found topics on tiers and wait but not 100% sure i understand them.

```
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var ITEMS  = "";

    function GetMovies(USERNAME, PASSWORD, ID) {

      var Movies = "";
      var URL = "http://localhost/api.php?username=" + USERNAME + "&password=" + PASSWORD + "&action=MOVIES&id=" + ID;
      $.getJSON(URL).done(function(RESULT) {

        $.each(RESULT.items, function(i, item) {

          var MOVIE_ID      = item.id;
          var MOVIE_NAME    = item.name;
          var MOVIE_POSTER  = item.poster;

          $( "#root" ).append( '<div class="movie" data-id="'+MOVIE_ID+'" onclick="PlayMedia(this);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">' );
          $( "#root" ).append( '<img class="logo" src="'+MOVIE_POSTER+'" alt="'+MOVIE_NAME+'">' );
          $( "#root" ).append( '</div>' );

        });


      });
      return Movies;
    }

      $(document).ready(function() {

        var genres = {};
        var XUSERNAME = 'Test010';
        var XPASSWORD = 'Test010';
        var ACTION    = 'MGENRES';
        var ID        = 0;

        var APIURL = "http://localhost/api.php?username=" + XUSERNAME + "&password=" + XPASSWORD + "&action=" + ACTION + "&id=" + ID;

        $.getJSON(APIURL).done(function(RESULT) {

          $.each(RESULT.items, function(i, item) {

            var GENRE_ID    = item.id;
            var GENRE_NAME  = item.name;

            $( "#root" ).append( '<p class="p">'+ GENRE_NAME +'</p>' );
            $( "#root" ).append( '<div class="reels">' );
            $( "#root" ).append( '<div class="starter"></div>' );

            GetMovies(XUSERNAME, XPASSWORD, GENRE_ID);

            $( "#root" ).append( '<div class="spacer"></div>' );
            $( "#root" ).append( '</div>' );
            $( "#root" ).append( '<div class="starter"></div>' );

          });

          $( "#root" ).append( '<p class="p"></p>' );
        });

        console.log(genres);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetMovies(USERNAME, PASSWORD, ID, GENRE_NAME) {
  var URL = "http://localhost/api.php?username=" + USERNAME + "&password=" + PASSWORD + "&action=MOVIES&id=" + ID;
  return $.getJSON(URL).done(function(RESULT) {
    $( "#root" ).append( '<p class="p">'+ GENRE_NAME +'</p>' );
    $( "#root" ).append( '<div class="reels">' );
    $( "#root" ).append( '<div class="starter"></div>' );

    $.each(RESULT.items, function(i, item) {
      var MOVIE_ID      = item.id;
      var MOVIE_NAME    = item.name;
      var MOVIE_POSTER  = item.poster;
      $( "#root" ).append( '<div class="movie" data-id="'+MOVIE_ID+'" onclick="PlayMedia(this);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">' );
      $( "#root" ).append( '<img class="logo" src="'+MOVIE_POSTER+'" alt="'+MOVIE_NAME+'">' );
      $( "#root" ).append( '</div>' );
    });

    $( "#root" ).append( '<div class="spacer"></div>' );
    $( "#root" ).append( '</div>' );
    $( "#root" ).append( '<div class="starter"></div>' );
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var genres = {};
  var XUSERNAME = 'Test010';
  var XPASSWORD = 'Test010';
  var ACTION    = 'MGENRES';
  var ID        = 0;

  var APIURL = "http://localhost/api.php?username=" + XUSERNAME + "&password=" + XPASSWORD + "&action=" + ACTION + "&id=" + ID;

  $.getJSON(APIURL).done(function(RESULT) {

    Promise.all(RESULT.items.map((item, i) => {
      var GENRE_ID    = item.id;
      var GENRE_NAME  = item.name;
      return GetMovies(XUSERNAME, XPASSWORD, GENRE_ID, GENRE_NAME);
    })).then((res)=>{
      console.log(genres);
      $( "#root" ).append( '<p class="p"></p>' );
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks i replace the contents of my function with the code you have provided now i am getting no output at all

maybe i could make the first request save the data to an array and then do a request for each item in the array and appaend the content returned from the request

Comment: Hi, so by this code we just made the asynchronous call a synchronous one.
If it's not working, the first thing that comes to my mind that the network call is not ended with "success" or the RESULT variable has a different structure. Please check that.

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

this is the message i am now getting

Comment: Oh really, it's deprecated :/ I will update my answer shortly ;)

Comment: Thanks for the update sadly this still has the same issue as my first set of code 

the movie genre options are appended one after each other but the movies that the second request are grabbing are not being displayed untill after all the grenres have posted so i am ended up with the following output 



genre name
genre name
genre name
genre name

instead of 



genre name 
- movies one
- movies two
- movie three
genre two 
- movie one
- movie two
- movie three

Comment: As I can't reproduce your code, I could not test is the proposed solution valid or not.
But here I created a similar example, and maybe by adapting your code, the problem will be solved: http://jsfiddle.net/aabramya/85r0acmx/1/

Comment: Thanks for this it seems like it dose what i want but i have no idea where i edit my code for it to go or how to match it to my requests doesmap work for mapping a json responce from an api call i will have a look about it thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer again. I hope that will work (I can't execute that), or at least will give an idea of how to adapt the code.

Comment: Thank you this is working good for my small list now sadly for larger lists with say 100+ movies it simply crashes the tab so i may have to look at alternative or possibly lazy loading for larger lists